# When saying "nominations are in", what does "in" mean?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, pronouns

What does *in* mean in the following sentence?

> MTV Europe Music Awards nominations are in and Lady Gaga leads

It feels like "announced", but does it refer to "in the news" or something? Where does it come from?

Comment: The nominations *are in [the hands of the judges]*, or whoever is responsible for collecting them and moving on to the next stage of the awards ritual.

Comment: Is there a *should be an answer* flag for comments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This sense of *in*](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/in_2) means

> **5** (of letters, etc.) **received**
>   *Applications must be in by April 30.*

Your example, *nominations are in and Lady Gaga leads,* makes it clear that the nominations have not merely been sent in, but already received by the judges, read, and tallied. However, sometimes a phrase like this refers more to the time of submission, implying that the item will also be received at that time, but might not be handled until later. For example:

> *The entries are in and we'll have the results next week.*  [The entries were received but not judged.]
>   *Get your votes in by noon on the 30th!* [Submit your votes by this time.]

This use of *in* often relates to judging—note the words like *nominations* and *votes*—but you might use it when referring to anything that is sent or submitted.

> *I already sent in the information you wanted.*  [I submitted it, to someone who will receive it.]
>   *Let me check—sorry, we didn't get that in yet.* [We haven't received it.]

Answer (score 0):

The *in* in the sentence refers to the nominations having been submitted and appropriately received.  We know they were received because there is an official tally in which Lady Gaga leads.

Etymologically, using the preposition *in* likely refers to a long-standing tradition among organizations to convene nominating people and things for awards, elections, and whatever by having those empowered to nominate submit their nominations by putting them in a hopper.  When nominations are *in* the hopper, they are *in*.  Colloquially and idiomatically, the preposition *in* is still used even if there is no hopper.